# Filter only by Date using MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using MongoDB C# latest driver i.e 3.+ in my project. I have different date filter criteria like Today, Last Day, Yesterday, This Month etc by using `daterangepicker`.

Here is my model:

```
public class Student
{
 public Student()
 {
 }

 [BsonId]
 [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
 public string Id { get; set; }
 [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
 public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
 [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
 public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the driver code:

```
var server = new MongoClient(_connectionString);
var db = server.GetDatabase("Students");
var collection = db.GetCollection<Student>("student");
var filterBuilder = Builders<Student>.Filter;
var start = new DateTime(2017, 03, 29);
var end = new DateTime(2017, 03, 31);
var filter = filterBuilder.Gte(x => x.CreatedOn, new BsonDateTime(start)) &
             filterBuilder.Lte(x => x.CreatedOn, new BsonDateTime(end));
List<Student> searchResult = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

This code works fine but when I select todays filter then the date becomes

```
var start = new DateTime(2017, 03, 31);
var end = new DateTime(2017, 03, 31);
```

It didn't returns records for the current day . It is calculating time also.

I am saving dates as `DateTime.Now`. Sample ISO Date which I am querying are:

```
"CreatedOn": ISODate("2017-03-31T20:27:12.914+05:00"),
"ModifiedOn": ISODate("2017-03-31T20:27:12.914+05:00"),
```

This is the dates filter I am using . Should I have to subract -1 from end dates?
[image: date example image]

Need help what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you add a  sample document from your collection that you are expecting your query for current day to return ?

Comment: I am saving DateTime.Now in database see my edited question

Comment: Thanls @Veeram for todays example I can use AddDays methods but what about others , I have updates the filter for dates I have . Need some kind of generic solution.

Comment: If I had to filter out dates in server side than whats the use of daterangepicker. Can I do that in client side ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I believe you are getting confused with time zones especially the offset part.

MongoDb always saves the date in UTC time.

So when you look at the date time in MongoDB you always have to factored in offset from your local time zone.

You'll always send the date in local time zone. Mongo C# driver changes time from local to UTC before persisting.

For example

When I save the document with `CreatedOn = 2017-04-05 15:21:23.234` ( local time zone (America/Chicago) ) but 
when you look at the documents in DB you will see something `ISODate("2017-04-05T20:21:23.234Z")` i.e local time offset from UTC which is -5 hours.

`[BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]` indicates to driver to convert the time to local time from UTC when deserailsing the BSON back to your POCO.

Here is the test case explaining the behavior.

**Code :**

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
        var db = mongo.GetDatabase("test");

        db.DropCollection("students");
        db.CreateCollection("students");

        var collection = db.GetCollection<Student>("students");

        var today = DateTime.Now; //2017-04-05 15:21:23.234
        var yesterday = today.AddDays(-1);//2017-04-04 15:21:23.234

        // Create 2 documents (yesterday &  today)
        collection.InsertMany(new[]
            {
            new Student{Description = "today", CreatedOn = today},
            new Student{Description = "yesterday", CreatedOn = yesterday},
            }
         );

        var filterBuilder1 = Builders<Student>.Filter;
        var filter1 = filterBuilder1.Eq(x => x.CreatedOn, today);
        List<Student> searchResult1 = collection.Find(filter1).ToList();

        Console.Write(searchResult1.Count == 1);

        var filterBuilder2 = Builders<Student>.Filter;
        var filter2 = filterBuilder2.Eq(x => x.CreatedOn, yesterday);
        List<Student> searchResult2 = collection.Find(filter2).ToList();

        Console.Write(searchResult2.Count == 1);

    }
}

public class Student
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Collection :** (when viewed through mongo shell)

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58e559c76d3a9d2cb0449d84"),
        "CreatedOn" : ISODate("2017-04-04T20:21:23.234Z"),
        "Description" : "yesterday"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58e559c76d3a9d2cb0449d85"),
        "CreatedOn" : ISODate("2017-04-05T20:21:23.234Z"),
        "Description" : "today"
}
```

**Update :**

```
"CreatedOn": ISODate("2017-03-31T20:27:12.914+05:00")
```

The reason your comparison is not working is

```
 var start = new DateTime(2017, 03, 31);
 var end = new DateTime(2017, 03, 31);
```

This gets send to server as as `$gte` than `ISODate("2017-03-31T00:00:00.000+05:00")` and `$lte` than `ISODate("2017-03-31T00:00:00.000+05:00")` and it doesnt find the above entry.

The right way to query for `today` date will be

```
 var start = new DateTime(2017, 03, 31);
 var end = new DateTime(2017, 04, 01);
```

and update your filter to

```
var filter = filterBuilder.Gte(x => x.CreatedOn, start) &
         filterBuilder.Lt(x => x.CreatedOn, end);
```

So now your range query is send to server as `$gte` than `ISODate("2017-03-31T00:00:00.000+05:00")` and `$lt` than `ISODate("2017-04-01T00:00:00.000+05:00")` and you should be able to find all matches for today.

**Update 2**

Change your database to store the date time with time part set to 00:00:00. This will remove the time part out of the equation from db too and your old range queries will work just fine for all cases.

Change your save method to use

```
var today = DateTime.Today; //2017-03-31 00:00:00.000
```

You can go back to old filter definition.

Something like

```
 var start = new DateTime(2017, 03, 31);
 var end = new DateTime(2017, 03, 31);
```

and update your filter to

```
var filter = filterBuilder.Gte(x => x.CreatedOn, start) &
         filterBuilder.Lte(x => x.CreatedOn, end);
```

So now your range query is send to server as `$gte` than `ISODate("2017-03-31T00:00:00.000+05:00")` and `$lte` than `ISODate("2017-03-31T00:00:00.000+05:00")` and you should be able to find all matches for today.

**Update 3** - Date only comparison using `BsonDocument`.

The idea here is to add timezone offset which is `+5:00` to the server's UTC date and transform the calculated datetime to string `yyyy-MM-dd` format using `$dateToSting` operator followed by comparison on input string date in the same format.

This will work in your timezone but **will not work in DST** observing time zones.

**Mongo Version 3.4**

You can use `$addFields` stage which adds new field `CreatedOnDate`while keeping all the existing properties and last `$project` to drop the `CreatedOnDate` from the final response after comparison.

Shell Query:

```
{
    "$addFields": {
        "CreatedOnDate": {
            "$dateToString": {
                "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                "date": {
                    "$add": ["$CreatedOn", 18000000]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
        "CreatedOnDate": {
            "$gte": "2017-03-31",
            "$lte": "2017-03-31"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "CreatedOnDate": 0
    }
}
```

C# code :

```
var start = new DateTime(2017, 03, 31);
var end = new DateTime(2017, 03, 31);

var addFields = BsonDocument.Parse("{$addFields: { CreatedOnDate: { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: {$add: ['$CreatedOn', 18000000] }} }} }");

var match = new BsonDocument("CreatedOnDate", new BsonDocument("$gte", start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).Add("$lte", end.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));

var project = new BsonDocument
     {
       { "CreatedOnDate", 0 }
     };

var pipeline = collection.Aggregate().AppendStage<BsonDocument>(addFields)
    .Match(match)
    .Project(project);

var list = pipeline.ToList();

List<Student> searchResult = list.Select(doc => BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Student>(doc)).ToList();
```

**Mongo Version = 3.2**

Same as above but this pipeline uses `$project` so you'll have to add all the fields that you want to keep in final response.

Shell Query:

```
{
    "$project": {
        "CreatedOn": 1,
        "Description": 1,
        "CreatedOnDate": {
            "$dateToString": {
                "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                "date": {
                    "$add": ["$CreatedOn", 18000000]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
        "CreatedOnDate": {
            "$gte": "2017-03-31",
            "$lte": "2017-03-31"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "CreatedOn": 1,
        "Description": 1
    }
}
```

C# code:

```
var start = new DateTime(2017, 03, 31);
var end = new DateTime(2017, 03, 31);

var project1 = new BsonDocument
    {
        { "CreatedOn", 1 },
        { "Description", 1 },
        { "CreatedOnDate", new BsonDocument("$dateToString", new BsonDocument("format", "%Y-%m-%d")
                            .Add("date", new BsonDocument("$add", new BsonArray(new object[] { "$CreatedOn", 5 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }))))
        }
    };

var match = new BsonDocument("CreatedOnDate", new BsonDocument("$gte", start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).Add("$lte", end.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));

var project2 = new BsonDocument
    {
        { "CreatedOn", 1 },
        { "Description", 1 }
    };


var pipeline = collection.Aggregate()
.Project(project1)
.Match(match)
.Project(project2);

var list = pipeline.ToList();

List<Student> searchResult = list.Select(doc => BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Student>(doc)).ToList();
```

**Update 4** - Date only comparison that works with day light savings.

**Mongo Version = 3.6**

Everything stays same expect `$dateToString` will take the timezone instead of fixed offset which should take care of day light saving changes into account.

Shell Update:

```
{
    "$addFields": {
        "CreatedOnDate": {
            "$dateToString": {
                "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                "date": "$CreatedOn",
                "timezone": "America/New_York"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

C# Update:

```
var addFields = BsonDocument.Parse("{$addFields: { CreatedOnDate: { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: "$CreatedOn", "timezone": "America/New_York"} }} }");
```

Comment: I want to store time part also how do I use in with your answer , you are not using DateTime.Now

Comment: Added time part to example. Use the `filterDefinition` from `Update` part of the answer for comparison queries.

Comment: If I had to filter out dates in server side than whats the use of daterangepicker. Can I do that in client side ?

Comment: Updated the answer to set the time part to 00:00:00 while creating records. So this will compare as if you are doing date only comparsions. Please give it a try and let me know what you find.

Comment: Basically I want to store the date with time , but filter records with only date . Since my UI showing time also

Comment: Sorry, I don't find a type safe way of doing date only comparison. One option could be to use `BsonDocument` to send the string date only value and compare against the server string date by offsetting the time difference and map the response back to domain object and I have updated answer with this approach. One more option would be to add + 1 day to end date before sending it to server and use first update to filter data. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Collection.Find()` with a Filter. In your Repository Pattern or wherever your code for database queries are, add this:

```
public async Task<List<T>> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
{
 try
 {
   // Fetch the filtered list from the Collection
   List<T> documents = await Collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
   // return the list
   return documents;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
   return await Task.FromResult(new List<T>() { });
  }
}
```

And call it this way:

```
_someClass.FindAll(x => x.UpdatedAt > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-5))
```

`_someClass` should definitely be replaced by the instance of the class containing the `FindAll` function.

Answer (score 0):

The following will display your POCO prop

```
    private DateTime _ShortDateOnly;
    [BsonElement("ShortDateOnly")]
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(DateOnly = true)]
    public DateTime ShortDateOnly {
        set { _ShortDateOnly = value; }
        get { return _ShortDateOnly.Date; }
    }
```

I used this to create the following BSON DOCUMENT

```
{{ 
    "_id" : CSUUID("12ce2538-2921-4da0-8211-9202da92d7f3"), 
    "first" : "Felipe", 
    "New" : "Ferreira", 
    "PublicPassword" : null, 
    "netWorth" : "20000.99", 
    "netWorth2" : 20000.990000000002, 
    "UserType" : "Admin", 
    "BirthDate" : ISODate("2019-06-22T18:59:01.861Z"), 
    "ShortDateOnly" : ISODate("2019-06-22T00:00:00Z") 
}}
```

Would you kindly Add the Following to your POCO and let me know if this has been minimally sufficient to get this working for you?

Answer (score -2):

When you use

```
new DateTime(2017, 03, 31);
```

You get a DateTime object, meaning it calculate the time also. 
So, by using the same parsing for the both start and stop, you actually get something equal to:

```
var start = var end = new DateTime("31/03/2017 00:00:00.00");
```

Sure, you probably have no record under this specific time frame. 
In case you really want to get all todays record, you should do something like that:

```
var start = new DateTime("31/03/2017 00:00:00.00");
var end =   new DateTime("31/03/2017 23:59:59.99");
```

Comment: @GhazanfarKhan He is here to help you. If he is wrong then just let him know. No need to use such language. Hope you understand.

Comment: Got it but I was not expecting this.