# Query Date only from MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to query a collection by **date only** to check if a corresponding record exist. I have tried a number of solution here and google searches but no success. How can i also save date and time to local time.

**Sample Collection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a4f8026762caf03f0a22114"),
    "AttnDate" : ISODate("2018-01-04T20:00:00.000Z"),
    "AllAttendances" : [ 
        {
            "FullName" : "MYDOMAIN\\Michelle",
            "Logged" : ISODate("2018-01-05T13:39:35.338Z"),
            "IdleTime" : 17
        }
    ]
}
```

**Attendance Class**

```
public class Attendance
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdConverter))]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
        public DateTime AttnDate { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<TimeRecord> AllAttendances { get; set; }
    }
```

**The Query method**

```
public Attendance FindAttendanceByDate(DateTime CurrentDate)
        {
            var filter = Builders<Attendance>.Filter.Eq(x => x.AttnDate, CurrentDate);
            return context.Attendances.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

How i am passing the CurrentDate on the above method

```
_AttendancesRepositories.FindAttendanceByDate(DateTime.Today);
```

**Solution**

In my case, i had to disable "Set time automatically" and "Set time zone automatically" in windows setting to get this to work. I dont know why. I may help someone to save 12 hours of their life.

Comment: You cant save datetime in local timezone unless you use string types. While running queries you can provide the timezone to interpret the datetime in local time zone in 3.6 version.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43167245/2683814) might help.

Comment: @Veeram `var start = CurrentDate;
            var ending = CurrentDate.AddDays(1);
            var filterbuilder = Builders<Attendance>.Filter;
            var fil = filterbuilder.Gte(x => x.AttnDate, start) & filterbuilder.Lt(x => x.AttnDate, ending);
            return context.Attendances.Find(fil).FirstOrDefault();` the method is still returning null.

Comment: Does it work when you pass date like ? `var start = new DateTime("2018-01-05");  var ending = new DateTime("2018-01-06");` The idea is to not include the time part or set to all zeros.

Comment: @Veeram It does not work

Comment: Can I see your code where you create a date object and document that you are expecting your query to return ?

Comment: @Veeram `var start1 = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).Day);
            var end2 = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day);
            var fil = filterbuilder.Gte(x => x.AttnDate, start1) & filterbuilder.Lt(x => x.AttnDate, end2);`  `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a4f910d762caf32c8cc6dc0"),
    "AttnDate" : ISODate("2018-01-05T14:51:57.582Z"),
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162610/discussion-between-aatish-kumar-and-veeram).

Comment: Try `var start = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc); & var end= new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).Day, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);`

Comment: Its likely a problem with timezones. `DateTime.UtcNow.Date` will give a UTC date object which should match with what is in your database. If you do `DateTime.Today` the `Kind` property is `Local` which presumably means it gets translated into the database "incorrectly". The moral of the story - always do your dates/times in the database in UTC.